# How to find element from inner class with python using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

i want to find element from inner class but the class name are same.
Website i am testing is: https://www.webull.com/quote/rankgainer
I try to get the three top gainer stock name

like:

there is a main div class = 'jss5249q3' and several inner classes having same name like:

```
<a class="jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu" href="/quote/nasdaq-ahpi" aria-label="View quote detail page of AHPI" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">AHPI</a>

<a class="jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu" href="/quote/nasdaq-osatw" aria-label="View quote detail page of OSATW" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">OSATW</a>
```

I tried this:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu"[2])
print(x.text)
```

It doesn't find the second element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select n-th row you can use this XPath

```
//div[@class='jsspuynws'][n]
```

So your code will be

```
row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='jsspuynws'][2]")
```

To get the `a` element with the href and the text use this

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='jsspuynws'][2]/a")
print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your code. it should not be **"[2])**, it should be changed to **")[2]**.

code should be,

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu")[2]
```

Comment: Then it should be `find_elements` not `find_element`